# How to check Logs of both main App and Extension App in iOS at the same time?

Tags: ios, xcode

I know how to view the logs for main app and extension app respectively.

But I'd like to check it at the same time. What is the easiest way I can use?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can view all logs at the same time!!.

XCode -> Window -> Devices and Simulators -> Open Console -> "You Can Filtering Log using Process Name"

But keep in mind. Only traces for os_log or NSLog are recorded.!!

Comment: Not NSLog. You should be using `os_log`.

Comment: @matt What I intended was that printf doesn't work. Thanks for the advice to use os_log. (NSLog is also output.)